# glibc detected free() invalid next size (fast) after convertion type C++

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I try to convert an **unsigned char*** to **string** but the problem I get this error from my console :

> glibc detected ** free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x097a1060

Minimized code :

```
unsigned char * base64= NULL;
base64 = (unsigned char *)"test";
std::string str((const char *)base64, strlen((const char*)base64)) ;
std::cout<<str;
```

PS : I have a function that returns an unsigned char*

Thank you.

Comment: Does your code use that function that returns an unsigned char rather than a literal "test"? If so, that function's body might be where the actual problem lies.

Comment: Btw, `(unsigned char *)` should really be `(const unsigned char *)`.

Comment: I think your function is returning a pointer that is no longer valid.

Comment: When I compile I don`t have an error just when I execute

Comment: Thats because its a run-time error.

Comment: @Mils We perceived that. (This is a civilized form of You don't say?)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're trying to free this pointer.

```
base64 = (unsigned char*)"test";
```

is a reference to a constant.  Here's my minimal example:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned char * base64= NULL;
        base64 = (unsigned char *)"test";
        std::string str((const char *)base64, strlen((const char*)base64)) ;
        std::cout<<str<<std::endl;

        free(base64);

        return 0;
}
```

That throws a glibc error and a core dump, as it should!  Without the free(), everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I included a librarie that contain errors.